# Access 2013 Fill table with a Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to execute a Select SQL-Command and fill my table with the information from the table.

This is my current progress:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM myOrder")
```

I got the information in my Recordset but I don't know how to put this into my table.
Please no bad comments, because I dont have many experience with VBA + Access so hope you guys can help me.

My table

```
|        myOrder                            |
|-------------------------------------------|
| aID | aAsset |  aOrdernumber | aSN        |
|  1  |  1235  |    12234156   | ASFF45432S |
|  2  |  1236  |    12541221   | WSABBS211Z |
```

This is my table and I want to execute the sql above to put the result of the recordset into my tableview.

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-24460.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Set RS = currentdb.openrecordset("SELECT * FROM myOrder")

'The code between RS.AddNew, and RS.Update will add records to the fields

RS.AddNew
     rs!aID = 3
     rs!aAsset = 1237
     rs!aOrdernumber = 11111111
     rs!aSN = AAAAAAAAAAA
RS.update
```

If you are editing existing information the correct syntax is:

```
RS.Edit
    rs!Field1 = "Test String"
RS.Update
```

Bare in mind this will start at the first record in the Recordset. You can loop through using

```
RS.MoveNext
RS.MoveFirst
RS.MoveLast
```

Or to loop right the way to the end of a Recordset you can use:

```
Do Until RS.EOF
'Do Something
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I will test it and will report the result then. Ty

Comment: I don't get it. How can this code fill my table in Access?

Comment: Can you post your field names and some example data? I can't see the names because you've used "SELECT * FROM myOrder" as your SQL.

Comment: I think we got a misunderstanding. The table above is my database and I got a Form with a table inside. This Table is just blank and i want to fill it with the information.

Comment: Yes, that is quite different. What is the name of your form and your subform?

Comment: "frmOrder" is the name of my main form but I dont know if i got a sub form or not. Sorry, but I don't have that much experience in access. 

I know that I've got 2 different ways to fill my form. 1. SQL via VBA or 2. Filter. 

Second way doenst work with my code either :(
    Me.Filter = "aOrdernumber LIKE '" & mySelectedRow & "'"